# Does a .NET technology for synchronizing local and remote SQL server databases exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

1) I am having a desktop application (machine A) using C# and SQL Server. I have another local  machine (machine B) it also has its own SQL server instance. I want to synchronize A’s database with B’database. This process should happen in a time interval.

2) I also have an ASP.NET web application running on web server (machine C). I also want to synchronize A’s database with C’s database. (SQL Server as well.)

I have to develop a solution for this problem. The problem is I am not quite sure what technology I am going to use. I have to use a .NET technology or similar Microsoft technology. Our main application was written in C#.

Comment: Define "Synchronize". Schemas? Data? Both? Full sync? Partial?

Comment: By synchronizing, do you mean Schema or Data or Both?

Comment: [Sync Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726002.aspx) maybe?

Comment: Thanks Oded ,Akil .I want to Synchronize Schema and Data.Should be partial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two MS tools you can use : [SQL-replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms151198.aspx), or [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb902854.aspx).

It depends on how deep and complex your problem is.  Like : do you want a fine-tuned tool, or everything-everytime kind of sync?  Also, another difference between the two is how you want to deal with "offline concurrency conflicts".  If on your servers A, B, C in your example, someone modifies a record in server A, while B has a copy of the previous version, modifies and posts it, which one should win, in your scenario?  Maybe the last one, maybe the first one, maybe no one at all?

SQL-Replication is out-of-the box in SQL Server (not the express version though).  MS-Sync Framework is parallel to the .NET framework but still free.

Comment: ya you are correct.There are lot on conflicting on that senario.I think the MS-Sync Framework is possible.I am going to explore this sdk also.Is there any tutorial rather than MSDN?

Comment: +! sync framework is tagreting exactly this scenario

Comment: The only source for info I used was the MSDN one...  It takes some time to scroll it all but it's rather well done.  I just searched and found a lot of other resources, though : http://alexduggleby.com/2007/12/16/sync-framework-tutorial-part-1-introduction/ http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2008/08/sync-101-samples-for-microsoft-sync.html http://www.developer.com/net/article.php/3813246/My-First-Microsoft-Sync-Framework-Application.htm

Comment: i Accept this answer Thanks every one ,Thanks very much.I got here what i need .Thanks stack over flow

Answer (score 4):

I would use Red Gate.  http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-comparison-sdk/

They do a great job with both data and schema synchronization.

Comment: Thanks .I will going to read about this .Because i want to give a possible pricing to our company .Is there any Opensouce SDK?

Comment: @Thabo - There isn't, but Red Gate has very reasonable pricing.  Especially when you consider the cost of the MS syncing solution for their enterprise product.  But if you have the Enterprise SQL use their solution -- it should work and only cost 10x as much.

Comment: mmmm That is true...I just now downloaded that trial sdk.I am trying to explore that sdk and develop a sample solution.it will help to compromise my company!:D

Comment: I'm the product manager for the Red Gate comparison and synchronization tools. Please feel free to contact me at David dot Atkinson at Red-Gate dot com if you need assistance.

Answer (score 4):

**SQL Server replication** can do this for you. It uses a publish-subscribe approach. I think you may be looking for "merge" replication.

This [one-page article](http://databases.about.com/cs/sqlserver/a/aa041303a.htm) will give you some highlights.

And [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151182.aspx) will tell you all the details.

**Edit**: Seeing that you are interested in pricing, replication is in all versions of SQL Server, but its functionality is very limited on the lower-end versions. However, if you have a higher-end version, it's included already.

Comment: Thanks i will check on those ......

Comment: No i am looking for some kine of SDK to learn new technologies.But the think is most of  companies always concerning technologies with pricing.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looking at Redgate's Sql Compare and Sql Data Compare http://www.red-gate.com/products/

Don't waste time/money reinventing the wheel :)

Comment: @Hogan to be fair he posted a minute after you, maybe you think alike, a lot of people use red gate, so it could of been just a timing thing (while you posted he was ready to click submit).

Comment: @JonH - hmmm, maybe I'm being grumpy.

Comment: @Hogan - don't be grumpy :) As soon as I posted my answer I saw yours and then upvoted it.  We're all friends here ... aren't we ;)

Comment: Haa haa haa great minds think alike.

Comment: @brodie - Very fair, I deleted my grumpy comment.